# Excel VBA "sum" producing unexpected value

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some issue with adding values in a loop in Excel VBA.

```
Set lookuprng = Worksheets("Offset Transactions").Range(Worksheets("Offset Transactions").Cells(startrow, 1), Worksheets("Offset Transactions").Cells(endrow, 7))
Set calrange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(67, numcols))

For Each searchdate In calrange
    datematch = Application.CountIf(lookuprng, cell.Value)
    If datematch > 0 Then
        For Each date In lookuprng
            If searchdate.Value = date.Value Then
                sum = sum + date.Offset(0, 6).Value
                MsgBox (date.Offset(0, 6).Value)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next date
    End If
Next searchdate
```

So in one range (lookuprng) is a list of dates and corresponding values.

In the other there is a list of dates (calrange).

I For Each loop through the calrange, and if there is a matching date in the lookup range, I loop through the lookuprange, and if the values match I add the corresponding value from the column offset (0,6) away to sum.

Using the MsgBox I can confirm that the correct values are being read, 8 message boxes show with the correct values that I want to sum, but the sum is incorrect - and not by the whole of one value, so its not like one is being missed -  each value is around 100,000, but the actual sum is 945,623 and the sum variable results in 944,047.

I've tried a few other approaches like putting them in an array then using application.sum but the result is the same, so really no sure what else to try as the *correct values are being added in the loop as per the msgbox output.* - EDIT: this was mistaken, I had overlooked something in earlier function that gets the searchrows and the loop was not correct. The issue was that startrow was incorrect. Following troubleshooting suggested below worked out as I tracked the sum in real time and found the issue.

Comment: Consider using `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs` here, instead of a loop.

Comment: Where do you `Set amount`?

Comment: Apologies, amount should be date - i had the loop originally as For each amount in lookuprng, but changed it to date when writing the question to try to make it clearer, I will edit the question to update.

I will look at using sumifs too and see what I can come up with.

Comment: The difference between 945,623 and 944,047 is 1576 which is 8 * 197 if that gives a clue. Add the sum into the msgbox to see where it goes wrong `MsgBox (date.Offset(0, 6).Value),vbInformation, sum`. Ensure `sum=0` before the loop.

Comment: Ah! OK, carefully watching with two msgboxes and adding up the values as I go along, I actually see the problem is that the last value it takes IS from the row above startrow instead of endrow. so the values in order are from row 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97... and then 90 instead of 98! So even more confused now. endrow is correctly = 98

Comment: You have 7 columns in lookuprng (are they all dates ?) but are offsetting by 6 to get values ? You could use resize `Set lookuprng = Worksheets("Offset Transactions").Cells(startrow, 1).Resize(endrow - startrow + 1, 7)
: Set calrange = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(67, numcols)`

Comment: I will try that, the lookup range is a table with transaction details - cols: date, id, from, to, amount, comments, acct balance. it is the balances I am trying to sum, so as to get an average balance between two suppled dates. ie i enter 1/7/2021 and 2/8/2021 and it sums all the balances and then will get an average. calrange is a calendar like grid of dates. I have a working function that looks up the date when cell is clicked on and returns the transaction detail.  startrow and endrow are from a search which finds the row where the date ( (or nearest to) is found

Comment: I have found the issue - startrow was incorrect as in earlier code i had left in startrow = startrow - 1 when i was trying something else. Thanks for the troublehsooting help though as using the msgbox to track the sum revealed the issue!

Comment: Since you only have dates in the first column Set lookuprng to column A only otherwise your loop `For Each date In lookuprng` is checking colums B:G unnecessarily.